# Finding the max element in a column of a matrix excluding certain rows

Tags: matlab, matrix, max

Consider I have an nxn matrix. My goal is to find the max element of the first column, swap the row containing that largest element and the first row. Next, I want to find the max element of the second column, excluding the first row, then swap the row of this new max element and the second row. Again, finding the max element of the jth column excluding rows 1:j-1, then swapping the max element row with the jth row, up until the n-1th column (as during the nth column, I would only be able to choose from the nth row).
My current setup for this is as follows

```
for j = 1:n-1
   [~,row]=max(A(j:n,j));
   temp = A(row,:);
   A(row,:)=A(j,:);
   A(j,:)=temp;
   ...
```

While the switching function works well enough, `[~, row]=max(A(j:n,j))` is able to, and consistently does for the matrix I'm specifically working on, output row 1 during the second iteration of j. My thought process behind this was that j:n represents the rows we want to check. Noting j=2, for its second iteration, I hoped this would search row 2-to-n; however, it seems to still check every row.

While this question has been asked before, the answer, I found, was this same line of code.

Comment: Do you really want to swap entire rows? this suggests that only the last column defines the final sorting of your matrix

Comment: Yes, this is in application to GEPP, so rows as a whole need swapping. As an example, the matrix [4,5,6; 1,2,3; 7,8,9]. I want the first iteration to output [7,8,9; 1,2,3; 4,5,6], on first iteration as max{2,1,7]=7, then [7,8,9; 4,5,6; 1,2,3], on the second iteration as max{2,5}=5. Tbh, it seems this algorithm, in the state I'm looking for, wouldn't consider the final column.

Comment: How do you end up with `max{2,1,7]=7`, I would expect the maximum of 7,1,4 according to your description.

Comment: My mistake. Yes, the desired result is max{4,1,7}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `[~,row]=max(A(j:n,j));`. Let's say you are in iteration j=2. max will only consider the input from the 2nd row on. A return value of row=1 indicates a maximum in the second row of A. The first row you put into the function. The max function has no clue that you actually input something larger. You have to correct for this.

```
n=5
A=magic(n); %just some input data

for j = 1:n-1
   [~,row]=max(A(j:n,j));
   row=row+j-1;
   temp = A(row,:);
   A(row,:)=A(j,:);
   A(j,:)=temp; 
end
```

by the way, matlab can do row swapping without helper variable:

```
for j = 1:n-1
   [~,row]=max(A(j:n,j));
   row=row+j-1;
   A([row,j],:)=A([j,row],:); 
end
```

Comment: Thank you, this was perfect. So, just to make sure I'm fully understanding, when using an interval like j:n, it (kind of) makes a new matrix which is the jth through nth column, and as you said, takes the jth column as the first and would take the nth column as the (n-j)th column? Also, thank you for the more concise row swap.

Comment: Yes, your understanding is right. `A(j:n,j)` creates a new matrix which is passed to the `max` function.